# Lost classes group in project navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have accidentally deleted the group on my project navigator that contains the classes (.m and .h) of my project. How can I restore it the way it was as a group? I tried dragging the folder from Finder but it creates a folder reference in the project navigator.

Comment: Use your version control to revert the change. You are using version control, right?

Comment: Im not sure what version control is but I'll take a look.

Comment: Okay after checking I did not take any snap shot so version control won't help, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you drag the folder into Xcode, you have to select "Create groups for any added folders".

Comment: Okay, so I've deleted the group that contains the .h and .m of my project. But its still there in Finder. I'll try this and get back for results.